# Distorted toggle in IOS build (ionic framework)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

For some reason some ionic components is distorted in build and doesn't looks like in web view.
Why this happens and how I can achieve correct render my elems?
For example toggle elem.

Web view:
[image]

Iphone emulator:

[image]